# React Composition vs Inheritance

Tags: reactjs

So I was going over the Inheritance vs Composition discussion all over the place. I will talk about my use case.

I am creating a hierarchy of components using react. Stuff like button -> buttonBar for example. So for these sort of things, whatever functionalities I have defined in the button component needs to be present as is in the buttonBar components.

```
class Button extends React.Component {
    shouldComponentUpdate()  {
        //do some prevalidation
        return result;
    }

    myButtonfn = () => {
        //do Something here
    }

    myButtonfn2 = () => {
        //doSomething else
    }
}

class ButtonBar extends Button {
    shouldComponentUpdate() {
        return myLogic && super.shouldComponentUpdate.call(this);
    }

    myButtonBarfn = () => {
        //I should be able to do this
        this.myButtonfn();
        this.myButtonfn2();
    }
}
```

Currently I have implemented inheritance to achieve this. What is the correct way of going about this? I don't want to go back to es5 way of using with this. React.createClass.

My usage of the functions in the component.

```
class Button extends React.Component {
    shouldComponentUpdate()  {
        //do some prevalidation
        return result;
    }

    myButtonfn = () => {
        //do Something here
    }

    myButtonfn2 = () => {
        //doSomething else
    }
}

class ButtonBar extends React.Component {
    doSomething = () => {
        this.refs.abcd.myButtonfn();//To be able to do this, HOC doesn't work
    }
    render = () => {
        return (<Button ref="abcd"/>);
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at higher order components - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html and passing your functions down as props

Comment: @TMitchell Just a thought, don't you think HOC is a bit too much for what he wants?

Comment: @TahnikMustasin too much in what sense?

Comment: @TMitchell I was guessing that his buttonbar was type of a button. So his buttonbar inherits button which makes perfect sense. He can of course use a HOC but if inheritence makes perfect sense then why HOC? Just my thought.

Comment: I don't think inheritance is a valid solution, facebook would agree https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. @TMitchell HOC is not what I need, since whatever functionalities I write in Button should be directly available in the instances of ButtonBar. Which won't be the case in HOC (You can argue by saying that you can give a ref to the button inside and using that ref to invoke it, but to even do that I need to write a function that does it). Plus HOC is creating unnecessary component hierarchy.

Comment: If using HOC you would pass the functionalities through as props and have access to them that way. It's certainly not the only solution, but it certainly is a valid solution

Comment: I'm not looking to pass functionalities. I have a cryptic way of using React, which most of the folks won't agree. I have some functions written in the component which will be invoked via a ref given to that component. So, the trigger is not any event, and I need functions written in the child directly available in the HOC which is not possible.

Comment: Take a look at the example added above.

Comment: @AftabKhan in that case I think you have answered your own question "What is the correct way of going about this?" with "I have a cryptic way of using React, which most of the folks won't agree"

Comment: Nope I disagree. If you look at the example I just added, people have used it like that. I'm not the only one. I'm using it like this in conjunction with passing down props.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
So you just edited your answer which looks exactly like my answer. This should the current way of using it.

---

If you can use es6 then you can create a class called button and your buttonBar can extend button to have all the functions of button.

Like this:

```
class Button {
  constructor(){
    //initialise stuff
  }

  doFoo(){
    //do foo stuff
  }
}

class ButtonBar extends Button{
  constructor(){
    //initialise stuff
  }

  doBar(){
    //do bar stuff
  }
}

let myButtonBar = new ButtonBar();
myButtonBar.doFoo();
```

Comment: This type of example works as they're just ES6 classes, but what about when it comes to React components as the author describes. You can't inherit a React component like this (without a third party library like ReactOO). The options are composition/higher order components

Comment: Yeah I mentioned "If you can use es6".

Also, from his later edit looks like he is indeed using ES6.

Comment: What I mean by 'just ES6 classes' is that they are not React components. I don't believe you can extend a React component in this way for it to behave in the way you would expect it to

Comment: I use es6 for all my components. But with es6 inheritance is throws errors at doing super in any other function except the constructor in babel. @TahnikMustasin. The edited example I have written tells that it doesn't work.

Comment: @TMitchell I'm able to extend React.Component and create my test example with that extended class. It works. It's not like it doesn't work. But I wanted to know if it was right thing to do. Plus if there is a better alternative

Comment: I don't think it is the right thing to do. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html facebook favour composition over inheritance

Comment: Agreed but not helping me for my usage. I've gone thru that article and Dan's article on medium.

Comment: @AftabKhan Why would it throw you error? I just tested it and it works. Check on the console here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MJjGwv

Comment: @TahnikMustasin I meant with es6 arrow functions as members, super doesn't work it doesn't work. Unfortunately codepen doesn't seem to support arrow functions for me to edit that.

Comment: Class inheritance works really well and is something I use regularly in React projects, but sparingly. React classes are ES6 classes and you can 100% absolutely them this way and this use case is a good example, although composition can be a better pattern depending on the use case.

Creating a base class for something like a 'Button' or even a 'Page' are good examples. I prefer it to scenarios involving a bunch of stacked HOCs to impart common core functionality.

Some discussion and examples of the different cases: http://blog.brew.com.hk/react-101-composition-vs-inheritance/

Answer (score 0):

```
class Button extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context){
       super(props, context);
       //set local state
     }
    shouldComponentUpdate()  {
        //do some prevalidation
        return result;
    }

   const  myButtonfn = () => {
        //do Something here
    }

    const myButtonfn2 = () => {
        //doSomething else
    }
}

class ButtonBar extends Button {

     constructor(props, context){
       super(props, context);
       //set local state
     }
    shouldComponentUpdate() {
        // No need to bind if you are call super method in ES6
        return myLogic && super.shouldComponentUpdate(); 
    }

    myButtonBarfn = () => {
        //I should be able to do this
        super.myButtonfn();
        super.myButtonfn2();
    }
}
```